# Unable to save SSIS 2015 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2015

I'm having some trouble saving an SSIS package to a SQL Server 2012 database.

In previous version of Visual Studio, I went to File > Save a copy of **** As.

As in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137565.aspx

It would then give me the option to select the server and a few other options.

However, in Visual Studio Community 2015 I get the below screen.

[image]

I'm using SSDT 2015, with my solution downgraded to 2012.

Is there a different way of uploading this to SQL Server now? Or am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/16b2f1b6-1fd7-49f4-9cb9-7c200e1c8b23/deploying-ssis-from-visual-studio-2015-to-sql-server-2014?forum=sqlintegrationservices

> SQL Server Data Tools Preview in Visual Studio 2015 is only target to
>   SSIS for SQL Server 2016 CTP3.0. SQL Server Data Tool Business
>   Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 is only target to SSIS for SQL
>   Server 2014.
>
> So to work around this issue, please recreate the package in SQL
>   Server Data Tool Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013, then
>   directly redeploy the project to SSISDB for SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I have. It gives the below error:
Package deployment mode is not supported on server with version lower than SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @b_en any idea why it seems that compatibily is set to SqlServer2016? Did you import de .dtsx?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of SSDT? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: I've got the latest version, I also think I've solved the problem. It looks like the package I was using was imported into a project prior to downgrading it to 2012. I just created a new solution and downgraded prior to importing (there was also a pop up about downgrading the imported package), I still can't 'save as' like previous versions of VS, but i can deploy to the server.

Answer (score 0):

There may have been issues with pre-release verions, but this should work fine now. (I just did one, SQL DT 2015 v 17.4 deploy to SQL Server 2014).

Remember to set TargetServerVersion in the project configuration properties and also - Remember to create the SSISDB database in the Integration Services Catalogs.  If this is not done, you can get the failed deployment messages.  (Easy to forget this if a new setup and focusing on the error messages.)

Answer (score 0):

fyi - I have created SSIS projects in VS2015 and deployed to SQL 2012 sp3 for quite a while until today when I received the message that I could not deploy to SQL < 2016.

Found I had to delete the project in Integration Services Catalog, recreate, deployment worked correctly again. As a test I made a small change to a package and could still deploy to SQL Server. Very odd.